# Simplest way to find which data types are most garbage collected?

Tags: haskell, profiling

I've looked around a little at the explanations of profiling but I'm not seeing a way to get straight at which data types are being garbage collected the most. Is there a way to do that?

Some of our code is running 50% or even 80% in the garbage collector, so... trying to track down what data types are being garbaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For profiling you can add quite a few options to the app when you run it.  Firstly you can add "+RTS -sstderr".  This gives you the broad stats that you described so I guess you already know this!

```
1,835,837,744 bytes allocated in the heap
328,944,448 bytes copied during GC
2,908,728 bytes maximum residency (25 sample(s))
142,056 bytes maximum slop
9 MB total memory in use (1 MB lost due to fragmentation)

Generation 0: 3483 collections, 0 parallel, 1.54s, 1.54s elapsed
Generation 1: 25 collections, 0 parallel, 0.09s, 0.07s elapsed

INIT time 0.00s ( 0.00s elapsed)
MUT time 3.04s ( 3.13s elapsed)
GC time 1.63s ( 1.61s elapsed)
RP time 0.00s ( 0.00s elapsed)
PROF time 0.00s ( 0.00s elapsed)
EXIT time 0.00s ( 0.00s elapsed)
Total time 4.67s ( 4.74s elapsed)
%GC time 34.9% (34.0% elapsed)
Alloc rate 603,893,994 bytes per MUT second
Productivity 65.1% of total user, 64.2% of total elapsed
```

As you can see from the example output above, I write some pretty bad Haskell.  You can delve into this more with some additional options and improve things.

1. -prof - Enables profiling
2. -caf-all - Constant Applicative form for all top-level items (constant costs, one for each module.)
3. -auto-all - Cost-centre analysis for every top-level function

Once you get the profiling information out, you can print out pretty pictures like the one below ([hp2ps](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/hp2ps.html)).  This shows allocation rates.  As you can see from below it's pretty simple to find the function that's doing too much work.

[image: Picture of the allocation rate of various functions]

Whilst this doesn't give per type information, it does help isolate what's happening.  I found [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html) to be tremendously useful.

Comment: You can get type information by running your program with +RTS -prof -hy -RTS.  Keep in mind that on some versions of GHC (in particular, the more recent ones), you may need to enable rts options when you build your program.

Comment: -hy seems to be what I want except... It talks about: "graph of live heap against time" but that's not what I want. I don't want to know the heap size, I want to know how much (and what type) garbage is being created which does not get retained on the heap.